# What are the frequencies used for within drones?

Tags: quadcopter, wireless, radio-control

What are these frequencies used for within the drone technology, and why these values?

- 35 MHz
- 433 MHz
- 868 MHz
- 2.4 GHz
- 5.8 GHz

Answer (score 2):

### Spectrum licensing

There are only a limited number of frequencies in unlicensed bands which can be used for radio control, and different countries have different licensed bands for different uses.

For instance:

- 35MHz is available for RC use in many countries in Europe, but other countries use a whole variety of other frequencies below 100MHz.

  - I found a wealth of information on this at the [UK Radio Control Council](http://www.ukrcc.org/index.html) website.
- 433MHz is in the [ISM Band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band) in [Region 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Telecommunication_Union_region)

  - That's the "industrial, scientific and medical radio bands" for use in "Europe, Africa, the Middle East west of the Persian Gulf including Iraq, the former Soviet Union and Mongolia".
- 868MHz is allowed for "Non-Specific Short Range Devices in Europe" within certain limits.
- Finally, both 2.4GHz and 5.8GHz are [ISM Band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band)s with worldwide availability.

I found much of this information in the [ISM-Band and Short Range Device Regulatory Compliance Overview](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra048/swra048.pdf) document from Texas Instruments.

### Frequency characteristics

In terms of actual use, different frequencies have different advantages and disadvantages. So in general:

- Lower frequencies require a larger antenna and generally have a lower data rate, but require less power and have fewer line of sight issues.
- Higher frequencies have more bandwidth available, so you can get more/wider channels and a higher data rate (see the [Shannon Hartley theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)) and you can can use smaller antenna, but line of sight starts to become a major issue, and you need more power for the same range.

Comment: Just as a follow-on comment to this answer, higher frequency transcievers allow for higher data rates.

Comment: That's worth an answer on it's own @Chuck, though technically, higher speeds are enabled by more/wider bandwidth channels rather than the frequency itself - you have many more 5MHz bands at 5.8GHz than at 100MHz *8') See the [Shannon Hartley theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).